# How do I change the permissions of the Boot folder?

Tags: windows-7, icacls

I want to change the permissions on the folder "C: \ Boot" on Windows 7. Currently the owner is TrustedInstaller. I make some changes with a script, but I need to have all permissions.

I tried it with the command icacls C:\Boot /T /grant Administrator:F but does not stop working well ....

What else could try? Can you think of something else to try?

I need to have all permissions in that folder, subfolders and files. No matter if they have all users.

I have also used the "takeown /f c:\Boot /r" command but not if necessary

Thanks!!

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the permissions.  What are you actually trying to do, and are you sure you are running the script "as admin" when trying to do it?

Comment: I need to change those permissions to change some files and do a deployment.

If I am the domain administrator, but the command is not working properly because it does not give the property to the administrator.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to change any of the existing files in there except perhaps BCD (which already gives administrators full access).  But the takeown command you've posted should work, so far as I can see.  It works on my system.  And so does the icacls command as posted, except that you may have meant Administrators rather than Administrator - unless you're logged on with the Administrator account?